# Lamp installation error: unable to resolve host

Tags: apt, lamp, tasksel

I get an error every time I try to install lamp with:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

My terminal looks like this :

```
root@(none):~# sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
tasksel: aptitude failed (100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the host error, it is because you don't have hostname set:

> root@(none):~#

You should set your hostname first:

```
sudo hostname ubuntu-server
```

Also check that your `/etc/hosts` file has a entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu-server
```

Then you need to have tasksel installed in your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Now you can use it:

```
sudo tasksel lamp-server
```

If you don't want to use tasksel, you could use:

```
sudo apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y install lamp-server^
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found many factors that could be reason for above issue.

Open up your terminal and type

```
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

After doing this also you got the same error means that due to MySQL. Purge MySQL if it is already installed. You shouldn't leave any a file.

Comment: i just created a new cloud server and after the update now i got this:
root@psbm-ptc02b02:~# sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo: unable to resolve host psbm-ptc02b02.pt.lunacloud.local
sudo: tasksel: command not found

if i try sudo apt-get install tasksel i get :
sudo: unable to resolve host psbm-ptc02b02.pt.lunacloud.local
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package tasksel

Comment: is your connection have any proxy setup

Comment: it's conected directly to the internet i think, im quite new to this.

Comment: ok try to change update server from software sources

Comment: i'm using ssh to access the server

Comment: ok from what ever the point you are doing this update... change that main update server

Comment: i got the same error but i think my problem is on this line : Sudo: unable to resolve host psbm-ptc01b07.pt.lunacloud.local and i don't know what that means :/

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try the following command as it had worked for me.

`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Comment: nothing get and error unable to resolve hostname psbm-frc01b01.fr.lunacloud.local and E: Unable to locate package lamp-server^
E: Couldn't find task 'lamp-server'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lamp-server^'

Comment: @RodolfoSilva then why you mark it as it answered your question?